# Implementing ARIMA(X) model in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, arima

I'm currently scratching my head about how I might implement a classic ARIMA(X) model using base TensorFlow (and optionally Keras). The equation I am attempting to setup has the following form:

[image: ARIMAX equation]

Where `d` represents the level of differencing applied to the input observed time series, `p` is the auto-regressive order, and `q` is the moving average order. The part which is stumping me currently is the calculation/estimation of the residuals `epsilon`. The auto-regression portion is a simple linear regression on the lagged samples, while the same is true for the terms involving the exogenous series (`X`). When I am estimating the residuals, should I simply feed the `q`-many previous steps into the current estimated parameters, and compute the residuals as `y_true-y_predict`? Though this also begs the question of: How does one estimate the residuals for observations where you have no previous observations? Do we simply estimate residuals 0 through `q` simply on a chosen random distribution of set variance (e.g. Normal, Poisson, etc.) with a mean of 0?

I have looked at the source for the `statsmodels` package to try to understand it, but it is quite opaque. Part of the reason for implementing the model this way is that it needs to fit into a fairly standard ecosystem at the company I work for, and we need control over what slices of data the model is fitted to at a given time step. This is because some data may arrive (much) later than the time stamp it relates to, due to lag at the source etc.

Thank you for any help you might be able to offer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help since it has been a while this question was asked. But [tensorflow_probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/overview) has added a section for Time Series and they have a class of an [ARIMA model](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/sts/AutoregressiveIntegratedMovingAverage) implemented in tensorflow.

```py
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

tfp.sts.AutoregressiveIntegratedMovingAverage(
        ar_order,
        ma_order,
        integration_degree=0,
        ar_coefficients_prior=None,
        ma_coefficients_prior=None,
        level_drift_prior=None,
        level_scale_prior=None,
        initial_state_prior=None,
        ar_coefficient_constraining_bijector=None,
        ma_coefficient_constraining_bijector=None,
        observed_time_series=None,
        name=None
    )
```

To [install](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/install) it (recommended to work with a virtual env):

```bash
pip install tensorflow-probability
```